# mongodb help required for one business problem

Tags: mongodb

Business Problem:
We are seeing a single customerOrderNumber with all versions having “INACTIVE.” This is a problem for multiple reasons. My goal is to be able to pull a list of customerOrderNumbers with ONLY INACTIVE statuses.

Database and Query: XXX_ORDERMGMT_1

```
db.getCollection('customerOrder').aggregate( [ { $match: { 'orderDocument.accountInfo.ban': '123456' } }, { $group: { _id: { customerOrderNumber : '$orderReference.customerOrderNumber', status : '$orderReference.customerOrderStatus' }, count: { $sum: 1 } }, }] )
```

OUTPUT:

```
/* 1 / { "_id" : { "customerOrderNumber" : "123", "status" : "COMPLETED" }, "count" : 1.0 } / 2 */ { "_id" : { "customerOrderNumber" : "123", "status" : "INACTIVE" }, "count" : 2.0 }
```

DESIRED_OUTPUT:

```
/* 1 */ { "_id" : { "customerOrderNumber" : "123", "statusGroupings" : { "status" : "COMPLETED", "status_cnt" : 1.0 }, { "status" : "INACTIVE", "status_cnt" : 2.0 } }, "count" : 3.0 }
```

( My approach was to pull all customerOrders by status and count, parse it into a relational format, and filter by only customerOrderNumbers with all versions being INACTIVE. This may not be the best way and I’m open to thoughts.)

Comment: Database and Query:
XXX_ORDERMGMT_1
db.getCollection('customerOrder').aggregate(  [
{ $match: { 'orderDocument.accountInfo.ban': '123456' } },
{ $group: { _id: 
{
customerOrderNumber : '$orderReference.customerOrderNumber', 
status : '$orderReference.customerOrderStatus'
},
count: { $sum: 1 }
},
}] )

OUTPUT:
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
"customerOrderNumber" : "123",
"status" : "COMPLETED"
},
"count" : 1.0
}

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
"customerOrderNumber" : "123",
"status" : "INACTIVE"
},
"count" : 2.0
}

Comment: DESIRED_OUTPUT:
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
"customerOrderNumber" : "123",
"statusGroupings" : {
"status" : "COMPLETED", 
"status_cnt" : 1.0
},
{
"status" : "INACTIVE", 
"status_cnt" : 2.0
}
},
"count" : 3.0
}                         so please let me know how to write a query to get the required output?

Comment: Remove the comments and make the changes to your question. Make sure to use code blocks.

Comment: when i try to do that i am not able to submit my query due to some format issue. so please can you help on the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query can get us the expected output:

```
db.getCollection("customerOrder").aggregate([
    {
        $match:{
            "orderDocument.accountInfo.ban":"123456"
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":{
                "customerOrderNumber":"$orderReference.customerOrderNumber",
                "status":"$orderReference.customerOrderStatus"
            },
            "customerOrderNumber":{
                $first:"$orderReference.customerOrderNumber"
            },
            "status":{
                $first:"$orderReference.customerOrderStatus"
            },
            "count":{
                $sum:1
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $group:{
            "_id":"$customerOrderNumber",
            "customerOrderNumber":{
                $first:"$customerOrderNumber"
            },
            "statusGroupings":{
                $push:{
                    "status":"$status",
                    "status_cnt":"$count"
                }
            },
            "count":{
                $sum:"$count"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        $project:{
            "_id":0
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Data set:**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bf7204ed5d873f39a773b"),
    "orderDocument" : {
        "accountInfo" : {
            "ban" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "orderReference" : {
        "customerOrderNumber" : 1,
        "customerOrderStatus" : "INACTIVE"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bf7204ed5d873f39a773c"),
    "orderDocument" : {
        "accountInfo" : {
            "ban" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "orderReference" : {
        "customerOrderNumber" : 1,
        "customerOrderStatus" : "COMPLETED"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bf7204ed5d873f39a773d"),
    "orderDocument" : {
        "accountInfo" : {
            "ban" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "orderReference" : {
        "customerOrderNumber" : 1,
        "customerOrderStatus" : "INACTIVE"
    }
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d9bf7204ed5d873f39a773e"),
    "orderDocument" : {
        "accountInfo" : {
            "ban" : "123456"
        }
    },
    "orderReference" : {
        "customerOrderNumber" : 1,
        "customerOrderStatus" : "INACTIVE"
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
{
    "customerOrderNumber" : 1,
    "statusGroupings" : [
        {
            "status" : "COMPLETED",
            "status_cnt" : 1
        },
        {
            "status" : "INACTIVE",
            "status_cnt" : 3
        }
    ],
    "count" : 4
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot S.Sharma. The query worked well and customer was happy too.

Comment: @Mamatha Please accept both the answers if these seem perfect to you.